# What is the chance that two random binary random variables are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Consider the space of probability distributions on 4 letters. Now all the probability distributions on four letters do not represent a distribution of two independent binary random variables.

But if we were to sample a distribution (on four letters) uniformly at random, what would be the probability that it represents a joint distribution of two independent binary random variables?

Comment: When you say $4$ letters, do you mean $\Sigma^4$ where $\Sigma$ is an alphabet?

Comment: I mean $|\Sigma| = 4$.

Comment: Zero, if the distribution of the distribution is diffuse.

Comment: what does it mean sampling a distribution uniformly at random ? does it mean choosing $P(X=a)$ randomly ?